# How to control the CutPoints(while performing supervised binning) in R

Tags: r, binning, discretization

I am using the 'discretization' package of R. While finding the cut points I am getting the following result.

Command :

```
discretization::cutPoints(data3$Dist_to_Stream, data3$Malaria_w3)
```

where `Dist_to_Stream` is a variable of numeric values and `Malaria_w3` is the class(categorical)

```
 [1]    5.118175   95.484400  119.386500  300.842000  311.320500
 [6]  338.104000  387.722500  460.783000  472.821500  551.741500
 [11]  910.745500  214.143000  234.124500  260.812000  358.513000
 [16]  361.015500  449.447500  538.411500  589.118500  626.888000
 [21]  657.261000  648.304500  698.310500  953.814500 1091.265000
 [26] 1181.350000 2023.885000 2040.360000 2069.390000 2201.395000
 [31] 2120.185000 2142.255000 2456.820000 2819.860000
```

The output cutpoints are too many(34 bins). Is there any way to control the number of cut points while supervised (entropy based) binning?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

The functions of the `discretization` package of `R` do not provide any such argument to control the number of bins ([Discretization Documentation](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/discretization/discretization.pdf)). Which can easily be done by the `Optimal Binning` option of SPSS. One can set the maximum number of bins(still its a supervised binning) before performing binning.

For more information
[Optimal Binning](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_16.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/clementine/binning_optimal.htm).